# Submitting like using Ajax within Laravel application

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So i've modified some code to add a Like function to a table called *sources*, this *sources* have the relation "hasMany" with the table *likes*.
It doesn't work and I don't get any errors, neither Javascript or PHP errors.

When I like the page it seems like the Ajax don't get called because the page reload to `/public/view#`, so nothing get submitted to the database.

I don't know how to sort this out.

**View:**

```
@foreach($post->sources as $source)
                    <a>{{$source['link']}}</a>
                    <div class="interaction" data-sourceid=" {{ $source['id'] }} ">
                        <a href="#" class="like-source">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('source_id', $source['id'])->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('source_id', $source['id'])->first()->like == 1 ? 'You like this source' : 'Like' : 'Like' }}</a> |
                        <a href="#" class="like-source">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('source_id', $source['id'])->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('source_id', $source['id'])->first()->like == -1 ? 'You don\'t like this source' : 'Dislike' : 'Dislike' }}</a>
                    </div>
                        <br>
@endforeach


<script>
    var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
    var urlLikeSource = '{{ route('likesource') }}';
</script>
```

**app.js:**

```
$('.like-source').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    sourceId = event.target.parentNode.dataset['sourceid'];
    var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null; //Checks if it's a like or dislike.

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLikeSource,
        data: {isLike: isLike, souceId: sourceId, _token: token}
    })
        .done(function(){
            //Change the page when .ajax has been executed.
            event.target.innerText = isLike ? event.target.innerText == 'Like' ? 'You like this source' : 'Like' : event.target.innerText == 'Dislike' ? 'You don\'t like this source' : 'Dislike';

            //Make sure you can't dislike and like at the same time.
            if(isLike){
                event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Dislike';
            } else {
                event.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = 'Like';
            }
        });
});
```

**routes:**

```
Route::post('/likesource', [
        'uses' => 'SourceController@sourceLikeSource',
        'as' => 'likesource'
    ]);
```

**SourceController.php:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Comment;
use App\Post;
use App\Like;
use App\Source;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;




class SourceController extends Controller{

    public function sourceLikeSource(Request $request)
    {
        $source_id = $request['sourceId'];
        $is_like = $request['isLike'] === 'true'; //Get's passed as string in request, changed to boolean.
        $update = false;

        //REDO WITH SMARTER SOLUTION
        if($is_like == 0){
            $is_like = -1;
        }

        $source = Source::find($source_id);
        if(!$source){
            return null;
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        $like = $user->likes()->where('source_id', $source_id)->first(); //First has to be specified
        if($like){
            $already_like = $like->like;
            $update = true;

            //Deletes if it already exists.
            if($already_like == $is_like){
                $like->delete();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            $like = new Like(); //Creates new row for Like in table
        }
        $like->like = $is_like; //Set's whatever $like->like to whatever $request['isLike'] passed.
        $like->user_id = $user->id;
        $like->source_id = $source_id;

        if($update){
            $like->update();
        }else{
            $like->save();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Like.php model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
    public function source()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Source');
    }
    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

**Source.php model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Source extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Rookie mistake by me, I cleared the browser cache. The browser used an old app.js file. Now the ajax seemed to get called correctly, however there's still no new rows in the *likes* table.

**Edit 2:**
I gave the data within the Ajax call sourceId: 1 and isLike: 2. There were still no new rows being created in the table *likes*.
So the problem seems to be in the **routes**, **controller** or any of the **models**.

**Edit 3:**
I changed the **route** to a route I knew works properly, I added a **csfr_token exception** to make sure the token wasn't screwing anything up. I made sure everything in the **models** were right and I finally made sure everything in the **controller** was being called correctly.

I truly can't find any problem.
The only thing I can think about is that the *likes* table "belongsTo" a lot of tables. I made the post_id, comment_id and source_id nullable when I created the table migration.

Should I use some other relationship in the models?

Comment: This is a JS issue. So you have no js errors? Does the click binding work?

Comment: If you mean this part `data-sourceid=" {{ $source['id'] }} "` when you say click binding? Yes, it seems like it's outputting the right source id when I inspect the web page.

And I believe I'm referencing it correctly in the JS too, `sourceId = event.target.parentNode.dataset['sourceid'];`